# Chang color of item in tableview when pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors, tableview

I have a tableview and the tableview is filled with items from a .plist.

I then use this method to add functionality to when something is pressed:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) { //do something
}

if (indexPath.row == 1) { //do something
}
```

So on and so forth

I've set a font color with in IB / The storyboard however I'd like to change the color of the text when it's being pressed. So basically I want it to act like a UIButton when it's pressed.

And of course not all text should be change when one cell is pressed, only the color of the text in the current cell that is being pressed.

Comment: change the text only or change the background color on the cell when u pressed the cell also

Comment: check my answer it is optimized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could change everything in the selected cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial"];
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView deSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial"];
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor = //default color;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for it go return to it's originally color after it's been pressed? So basically when pressed it will change color and when released it will return to the original color

Comment: you should use same code with default color in deSelectRowAtIndexPath @user243318

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];


 if (indexPath.row == 0) 
 { 
   cell.labelText.color = [UIColor redColor];
 }

 if (indexPath.row == 1) 
 { 
 cell.labelText.color = [UIColor greenColor];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option (I assume you have a UITableViewCell subclass MyTableViewCell, adjust as needed):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) { //do something
}

if (indexPath.row == 1) { //do something
}

MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// Adjust your cell contents as needed
```

Also add deselection delegate method to revert changes:

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Adjust your cell contents back to normal
```

Another option would be to override setSelected:animated: and setHighlighted:animated in your UITableViewCell subclass and make appropriate changes to cell elements there.